# I want to run npm install and grunt in the background

Tags: node.js

So I have code in node, I want to run npm install and grunt in the background. npm install should run before grunt runs. Both both should run in the asynchronously. How can I get this done using node?

Answer (score 0):

Shelling out the commands from within node, it will look like this:

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('npm install && grunt', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }
  console.log(stdout);
});
```

If you want to run both as described, in the background from you shell just run

```
npm install && grunt &
```

To write the output to a file, you could do

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('npm install && grunt', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
  fs.writeFile('outputOfNpmInstallPlusGrunt.txt', stdout, () => { ... })
}
```

Conversely, using spawn this would look something like:

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

function makeRunner(name, cb) {
  var ls = spawn(name, []);
  var output =  '';
  ls.stdout.on('data', (data) => { output += data; });

  ls.on('close', (code) => {
    fs.writeFile(name.split(' ').join('-'), output, cb);
  });
}

makeRunner('npm install', () => makeRunner('grunt'));
```

Comment: What's the difference between this and using spawn?

Comment: spawn returns a stream for you to listen to the stdout form the spawned process and act on each stdout as it happends, where as this exec is more a short hand if you just straight up want to run the thing and get the output afterwards.

Comment: Don't you need to run `(npm install && grunt) &` if you want to run both in the background? `npm install && grunt &` will run `npm install` in the foreground, then when it finishes it will run grunt in the background.

Comment: so I want to use spawn so I can get the output written to a file. How can I use spawn to run both commands sequentially?

Comment: @PaulHicks You are correct, I just assumed that the OP would want to have the npm install finish before trying to use grunt.

Comment: @BrownKL I updated the answer to demonstrate a couple more cases

Comment: @Belfordz When you do `(npm install && grunt) &` , the npm does finish before grunt starts. That syntax starts up a new shell in the background, then runs npm in the foreground of that (backgrounded) shell, then runs grunt in the foreground of that (backgrounded) shell.